# My web app running in EC2 is accessible to the world via AWS Public DNS. Is this good or bad?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

I'm running a web app in EC2 and the it is accessible via mydomainname.com. however it's also accessible on AWS Public DNS which looks like ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com. Im running nginx and I'm already redirecting my elastic IP to go to mydomainname.com. Can I redirect AWS Public DNS too the same way? Having the web app accessible via AWS Public DNS is good or bad?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with AWS, and is related to how you set up your web server. It sounds like you have one config that responds to all requests.

If you only want the web server to respond to your domain, and not the AWS hostname, configure a name-based virtualhost for your host name.  Configure nginx so that the default delivers a blank page, or throws an error, or redirects users to your domain - the choice is yours.

Comment: +1 and to clarify slightly, what's being configured here is the way your web server interprets the incoming `Host:` header.  My position is that an unexpected value here should be treated as an error, with a response to match.  I see a lot of traffic for my AWS IP addresses, ec2 hostnames, and even ELB hostnames, and, with an exception for health checks, I respond with various errors (400, 404, 410, 500, 502, 503... depending on my mood, lol) and with a `/robots.txt` that denies everything, so search engines won't index anything at the invalid hostname.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm getting a little confidence now with what options I have. If possible can you please post resource links to support your answers, both of you Chris and Michael.